# Inline tag links rendered in plain text on the "tagged" page for a tag

Tags: bug, tags, tag-wiki, tag-links

In the [google-mirror-api](/questions/tagged/google-mirror-api) tag, the wiki text includes an inline link to the [google-glass](/questions/tagged/google-glass) tag. On the [info page for the tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-mirror-api/info), it shows up as [google-glass](/questions/tagged/google-glass); however, on [the tagged page for google-mirror-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-mirror-api) (which imports the wiki text) the link to the tag is rendered in plain text as `[tag:google-glass]` instead of an actual tag link.

I would think it should be an actual tag link. But if the plain text is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), should it maybe render just the tag name (e.g. "google-glass")?

Comment: This is by design, it's just not interpreted in there. (Someone already removed it from that tag excerpt.)